# I cannot boot from anything except HDD (rare case) stuck with unresponsive BIOS and Debian CLI

Tags: linux, boot, debian, bios

Sorry for the amount of info in this question, but I think it's necessary since this case is so rare. Also, I cannot answer 10 times a day to your demands of more information, so I prefer putting everything in my original post.
Question is in bold at the bottom if you wish to skip all my blah-blah.

A bit of background information :

I'm planning on creating my own home server with a Raspberry Pi 4 and software called OpenMediaVault ([OMV](https://openmediavault.org)) which runs

- Either as a modded Debian that I install through a live CD, DVD, or USB (as a new OS)
- Either from a simple app that I install on top of Debian (or Raspbian) with a command

In any case, I am left with **a bash CLI**.

But there are no Raspberry Pi in stock for a reasonable price (I live in France so I want something from EU to avoid paying taxes and import duties) so I decided to use an old (2005 or so) laptop I have : i386 Sony Vaio laptop which *had* Windows XP preinstalled.
But OMV has dropped support for 32 bit version of the OS since version 3. So that was the one I had to install.
If I install on top of Debian using the command, though, that's fine, and I can get the latest version (6)
But I didn't realize that at first...

OK, now to the problem itself (pictures of BIOS on [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/191SBc8RDhD52YmmNG2x3kV4-r5qWBSCr?usp=sharing)):

I can access the BIOS.
Since the PC hasn't been used for 10 years, the CMOS battery died and the date and time was reset when I turned the laptop on 3 days ago...

The CD-ROM drive doesn't work (Windows XP cannot see any CD put in it) but the USB do work : whether I plug a thumb drive or my external CD/DVD reader/burner, *Windows* sees them.

But when I plug in any of these devices before boot, press f2, go to the boot tab, the devices types (that's "Removable Drives", "CD-ROM drive", "Internal drives" and "Network boot") have no sub-menu indicating the devices except for "Internal drives" which does detect if I pull in or out the -- 30 GB -- HDD.

This BIOS being old, there is no option for FastBoot or SecureBoot and I imagine it's using Legacy boot (but again there is no option)

I have put the removable as first in the boot menu, though.

I then thought about bypassing the BIOS and accessing the boot menu using `esc`, `f10`, `f11`, `f12`, or `del`.
But all that does, is to do one continuous beep until I let go, and then it boots up normally. No boot menu in sight...

I had Windows XP installed, so I resulted to using [PLOP boot manager](https://plop.at). Worked great !

But I was so happy that installed the OMV OS, which limits to version 2 for 32 bit machines. I am now stuck with quite crappy software.

Why stuck ? Because I cannot boot from anything else to install Debian and then use the command : I have tried using GRUB to boot using the `set root=(hd1,msdos1)` but again there is no such drive, only `(hd0)`.

Many tutorials say to use a Live-CD to boot into PLOP Linux, which loads USB drivers and makes it possible to boot from USB, but I cannot get a CD to work !

So the question is :

**How do I boot from USB (thumb drive or external CD/DVD reader, don't care), when BIOS doesn't detect anything except internal HDD, GRUB either, and I've only got in front of me :**

- **A GRUB CLI**
- **A Debian bash CLI**

Thanks for any kind of answer, because I am desperate now... 
Silloky

Comment: I think you should just pull out the internal drive, get a USB-IDE adapter, than install whatever distro you want (and that would work on this old laptop) to it using another PC, and stuff it back to the laptop. (If the ultimate goal is to have the main part of the installation on another USB HDD, then use the old hard drive for only `/boot`.)

Comment: @TomYan And so I boot up the Debian installer on a valid PC and I choose to install on the IDE drive. Is that right ?

Comment: Yeah if you are fine with the whole OS on this old and small drive, or you could use it for only `/boot` (i.e. where the kernel and initramfs reside), as I said. Make sure you install for BIOS boot mode (so this "valid" PC might *need* to be able to boot the installer in BIOS/legacy mode instead of UEFI mode in the first place). It's might be even better to install with a VM on this "valid" PC, so that the installer will not have a chance to tamper the installation on this "valid" PC (although raw disk access might be tricky and dangerous if your not familiar with stuff).

Comment: Not familiar with Debian but it should have a "fallback" initramfs which allows you to boot this installation created via USB when it is stuff back to the IDE.